# PostgreSQL - statistic for days and display days with no data

Tags: postgresql

there have already been similar questions, but I do not understand how to connect my situation with past examples.

I need to display data for a period. Moreover, if the value is zero, then this data must also be present. I understand that this can be done through the LEFT JOIN . But how is unclear.

Right now my query is something like this:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', to_timestamp(created_at)) as "Interval", COUNT(*) as "Number" FROM public.surmise 
where
GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1
```

I get:

```
January 1 - 10
January 3 - 20
January 10 - 5
```

I want:

```
January 1 - 10
January 2 - 0
January 3 - 20
January 4 - 0
... 'other days with 0'
January 10 - 5
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a list of all dates without gaps (`generate_series`) and then select from this list `left join` your table so that all the dates will be in the result. Please note that the result is correct because `COUNT(s.created_at)` does not count null values.

```sql
SELECT date_trunc('day', to_timestamp(s.created_at)) as "Interval",
   COUNT(s.created_at) as "Number" 
FROM 
  generate_series('2022-01-01', '2022-01-10', interval '1 day') as gs(d) 
  left outer join public.surmise s on s.created_at::date = gs.d::date
GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1;
```